# How to specify SDK source code of another api level in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio with latest SDK level 30, android R.
Current SDK does not have source code included, so when I click on some SDK Api trying to look at the source, it just give decompiled .class file, which does not make any sense for me.

I know the SDK source is different on different releases, however, if I just want to see the source code (maybe 90% the same) of the former SDK version, how can I tell Android studio to do so?

E.g. I have the SDK-29 source downloaded, but my APP has to target SDK-30 for compatibility test. During my development work, if I want to have a glance of the source code of an API (especially the old routines introduced since years ago), how can I tell the Android studio to load available source of a newer SDK version?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this isn't possible. But we can duplicate the project and change its `targetSdkVersion` to 29, and change IDE preference as below:
[image]

Now we could open two projects simultaneously. if you want to view SDK source codes, just switch to the specific project.

Answer (score 0):

Change both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 29. Make sure you also download the sources for API 29. In the "SDK Manager", tick the "Show package details" checkbox, tick the "Sources for Android 29" and hit apply.